# Create Date Time Managed properties in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property

What I wan't to achieve is to create a site column with type DateTime which I may query via the rest api by range (><).

At the moment the only type options available in create new managed property are text or yes/no.

How do I create a column that is queryable, retrievable via the query?querytext endpoint of type edm.DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Map your crawled properties to the MPs `RefinableDateNN`.

Comment: that does not return in date time format, it basically returns the value in string format